# Parameterize / Configure connection strings, account-name, account key of Azure blob storage in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am trying to parameterize Azure blob storage connection string; can someone suggest the best way to do it, so that the account key is secured and we can update it for different environments.
We are not using azure key vaults. But we have our own vault.